# Set range and label for axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm ploting data from an array A of size 10*10, each element `A[x,y]` is calculated by a function `f(x,y)` where x and y are in the range `(-3, 3)`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x,y):
    return ...

s = 10
a = np.linspace(-3, 3, s)
fxy = np.array([f(x,y) for x in a for y in a]).reshape((s, s))

plt.xticks(labels=np.arange(-3, 3), ticks=range(6))
plt.yticks(labels=np.arange(-3, 3), ticks=range(6))
plt.imshow(fxy)
```

[image]

So the labels on xy-axis are not that I want since x and y are taken from the range `(-3, 3)` (not from `(0, 10)` which is the size of the 2d-array). How can I set these labels correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `extent` argument in `imshow` and it will handle the tick labels automatically.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x,y):
    return ...

s = 10
a = np.linspace(-3, 3, s)
fxy = np.array([f(x,y) for x in a for y in a]).reshape((s, s))

plt.imshow(fxy, extent = [a[0], a[-1], a[-1], a[0]])
```